# C program using fork to determine the number of characters in a string

Tags: c, fork

I need to determine the number of characters in a string using fork.
I need to run the program as "foo" followed by the string.

for example:
input: foo stack overflow
output: 13

my code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
int i;
int sum = 0;
int status;
int len;
char str;

for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) { 
 int pid = fork();

 if (pid < 0) { 
  perror("fork() failed");
  exit(1);} 

 else if (pid == 0) { 
    str = argv[i];
    len = strlen(str);
    sum = sum + len;
    exit(1);}

 else{
    exit(1);}} 

printf("The length of all the args is %d\n, sum");
return 0;}
```

the errors I am receiving are

```
    main.c: In function ‘main’:

    main.c:21:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fork’ [- 
    Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       21 |  int pid = fork();
          |            ^~~~
    main.c:28:9: warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes 
    integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       28 |     str = argv[i];
          |         ^
    main.c:29:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ makes pointer 
    from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       29 |     len = strlen(str);
          |                  ^~~
          |                  |
          |                  char
    In file included from main.c:11:
    /usr/include/string.h:385:35: note: expected ‘const char *’ but 
    argument is of type ‘char’
      385 | extern size_t strlen (const char *__s)
          |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
    main.c:36:40: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument 
    [-Wformat=]
       36 | printf("The length of all the args is %d\n, sum");
          |                                       ~^
          |                                        |
          |                                        int
```

If anyone could help me figure out how to do this efficiently and remove my errors that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation of the function [`fork`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). In particular, please pay special attention to the header file that is required to use that function. The term "implicit declaration" simply means that the function has not been declared and that the compiler is therefore assuming that it is to be declared implicitly. However, you don't want an implicit declaration. You want it to be declared explicitly, by including the appropriate header file.

Comment: I have included the header file, it was just my mistake in pasting my code here.

Comment: Are you claiming that your actual code includes the line `#include <unistd.h>`?

Comment: yes correct, that takes care of the first error however the next 4 errors remain. That is where my confusion lays

Comment: The line `str = argv[i];` does not make sense. You are assigning a value of type `char *` (i.e. a pointer) to a variable of type `char`. You probably want to make `str` also a `char *`, so you must change the line `char str;` to `char *str;`.

Comment: The `exit(1);` indicates 'failure'.  Your first child exits; your parent exits; the second child for the second string never gets run.  You need to review how to get information from the child processes back to the parent process — your course notes must cover that.

Comment: Oh, and you need a format string and a separate argument to provide the value for the `%d` conversion specification in the format string.  Your format string swallowed the name of the variable holding the value to be formatted.

Comment: "using fork to determine the number of characters in a string" That's kind of like using a hammer for securing a screw instead of a screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help you with some stuff but heres some.
`char str` should be `char* str`, you can see one of your errors comes from trying to assign a char*, from the argv to the str variable which takes only char. Char isn't a string, its a character while char* could be an array of characters, which is a "string" in a way. This is probably what is also causing the error with the strlen(), if not try doing str.strlen() but I don't think thats the problem. When it comes to the last error, you were almost right but while you are inside the "", everything you write is still a string, the correct format is `printf("The length of all the args is %d\n", sum)` . Only one last thing, I don't believe this code will work because fork() creates a process, and processes don't share memory, they create a copy of the memory when created and then write to it, meaning, instead of having one variable sum to which all the processes write to, each process will have a variable sum. One way to do this would be using threads instead of processes as they share the same memory, or maybe use named pipes to talk between processes, I recently did a project with pipes and it was quite helpful. Last thing, on the else, you exited the parent process so no process will reach the printf at the end